# Excel VBA: Sort rows Numerically (by column value) THEN sort by one specific string

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know if this is the right approach for this. But here goes. I have some excel data:

```
Column 1 |  Column 2
1        |   open
3        |   issue
7        |   closed
8        |   open
```

I need to sort by column 2 (all columns with 'open' at top of list but with a numerical sort also so the row with '8,Open' would be at the top) then the rest of the rows need sorting only numerically highest numbers first.

resulting in:

```
Column 1 |  Column 2
8        |   open
1        |   open
7        |   closed
3        |   issue
```

Below is my code for the numeric only (column 12). I need help with the other aspect.

```
With ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Selection.EntireRow.Columns(12), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SetRange ActiveSheet.Range(Data)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Range("B1"), xlSortOnValues, xlAscending, "Open"
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Range("A1"), xlSortOnValues, xlDescending
With ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SetRange Range(Data)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

**EDIT**:
**_________________________________________________________________________________**

```
Dim SortStr As Variant
Dim SortNum As Long

'change below array as per your requirement
SortStr = Array("Open", "in progress", "almost finished")   
Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=SortStr
SortNum = Application.CustomListCount

ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Range("B1"), xlSortOnValues, xlAscending, SortNum
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Range("A1"), xlSortOnValues, xlDescending
With ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SetRange Range(Data)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Application.DeleteCustomList Application.CustomListCount
```

Comment: If I wanted to sort by an additional keywords like  "in progress", then "almost finished" how would I add those elements. So all 'Opens at the top numerically, then all "in progress" numerically, etc.

Comment: Ok one more thing, the numeric sort is working BUT, blank fields are at the TOP, if I want BLANK fields to the bottom what must I do?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `Sort` method of the `Range` object

```
Dim iniRow As Long

With Range("Data")
    .Sort key1:=.Range("B1"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes '<~~ first sort by column 2 ("B" in my test)
    iniRow = Application.CountIf(.Columns(2).Cells, "open") '<~~ then count how many "open" are there
    .Offset(iniRow + 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - (iniRow + 1)).Sort key1:=.Range("A" & iniRow + 2), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo '<~~ finally order remaining by column 1 ("A" in my test)
End With
```

Comment: @user937036: did you give it a shot?